# React with redux and component vs. container dilemma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to organize my code into `components` and `containers` folder structure. I will be using Redux with actions and reducers.

What do you think that `StartButton` is rather component or container? It will not be connected to the redux store, but it has its own state and some decision logic, so maybe it isn't so dumb...

I know my question has something to do with opinions, but perhaps someone can provide me with some insights and what's regarded as best practice.

Here's my StartButton component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

import './style.css';

class StartButton extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      startWasClicked: false,
    };
  }

  handleStartButton = () => {
    this.setState({ startWasClicked: true });
  };

  beerListingView() {
    if (this.state.startWasClicked) {
      return <div>YES! It was clicked!</div>;
    }
    // Else return just single <div />
    return <div />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="StartButton-container">
          <RaisedButton
            label="Start Here"
            className="StartButton-main"
            onClick={this.handleStartButton}
          />
        </div>
        {this.beerListingView()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StartButton;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my apps, `containers` refer to react components that are connected to the Redux store.

`components` are all the others. Most of them make use of the React state to toggle UI stuff for example. Thats perfectly fine.

Check out https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate for example